# How is this way of writing ansible task named? Is it deprecated?

Tags: ansible

I have an old ansible repository that I forked some time ago (2 years+) where I had not much idea about ansible. There are a lot of tasks written in a form that I don't know if it is correct or if it is deprecated. They use the `action:` section of the task, and then they write what looks like standard ansible actions (in fact, ansible-link complains that I should use FQN for built in actions on those).

I tried searching but all the results that I find are not relevant, so I am asking here how is this module `action` usually referred to, and should I change it to plain yaml?

```
- name: Disallow password authentication
  action: lineinfile dest=/etc/ssh/sshd_config regexp="^PasswordAuthentication" line="PasswordAuthentication no" state=present
  notify: restart ssh
```

Comment: For Ansible versions > 2.9, using FQN is preferable (apart from using YAML syntax), so you should have `ansible.builtin.lineinfile:` with the module's parameters below it.

Comment: And can you point me to some documentation about the `action:` section/keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question

> How is this module `action` usually referred to

you may have a look into [Playbook Keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html)

> "*For example, action in task can be substituted by the name of any Ansible module.*"

> "*The ‘action’ to execute for a task, it normally translates into a C(module) or action plugin.*".

Regarding your question

> Is it deprecated?

Since it is referenced in the actual documenation without a note it seems to be not.

Regarding your question

> There are a lot of tasks written in a form that I don't know if it is correct

Since it is referenced in the actual documenation without a note it seems to  be correct syntax.

Therefore it is possible to write tasks like

```yaml
  - name: Gather stored entitlement from repository service
    action:
      module: uri
      url: "https://{{ REPOSITORY_URL }}/api/system/security/certificates"
      method: GET
      url_username: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      url_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
      validate_certs: yes
      return_content: yes
      status_code: 200
      body_format: json
    check_mode: false
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result.json }}"
    check_mode: false
```

which in example gather installed certificates from a JFrog Artifactory repository service via REST API call, as well

```yaml
  - name: Gather stored entitlement from repository service
    local_action:
      module: uri
      ...
```

> `local_action`
> Same as action but also implies `delegate_to: localhost`

for [Controlling where tasks run: delegation and local actions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html).

Nevertheless, [the YAML format is the best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71515141/6771046). Therefore you should change it to plain YAML if possible.

Comment: I indeed looked the documentation, but what I saw there gave me no clue of what the actual meaning was: `The ‘action’ to execute for a task, it normally translates into a C(module)`. Since there is no reference on the manual that explains what actions are (they are not tasks, nor modules, nor plugins, just actions...) and `C(module)` is something I don't know what is and it's impossible to google. Thanks for clarifying what the meaning is. Seems that the term `module` can be skip on the one-line version, and all it needs is just the module name, right?

Comment: @Danielo515, regarding `C(module)` you may have a look into [Linking and other format macros within module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_documenting.html#linking-and-other-format-macros-within-module-documentation) from the [Developer Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/) and maybe the source code of [`lib/ansible/modules/lineinfile.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/lineinfile.py). It is indeed something which is more related to module development.

Comment: @Danielo515, regarding "_the term `module` can be skip on the one-line version, and all it needs is just the module name_", right. In the one-line notation it can be skipped since it is clear that there will be the module name followed by the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***"Should I change it to plain YAML?"***

A: Yes. The YAML format is the best practice

```yaml
- name: Disallow password authentication
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: "^PasswordAuthentication"
    line: "PasswordAuthentication no"
    state: present
  notify: restart ssh
```

To see details and examples about *lineinfile* run

```sh
shell> ansible-doc -t module lineinfile
```

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation about the `action:` section/keyword